# segment a python dataframe to run a function in each segment

Tags: function, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to run a function that works for my data set (almost). The fact is that when I use my whole data frame my function doesn't work.
The heading of data frame looks at follows:

```
           ID   POSITION_X  POSITION_Y  POSITION_T
0           0     116.231     114.277           0
1           0     116.131     114.376           1
2           0     116.189     114.364           2
3           1     116.150     114.398           0
4           1     116.271     114.375           1
5           2     116.157     114.296           0
6           2     116.220     114.384           1
7           2     116.221     114.280           2
8           2     116.277     114.489           3
9           3     116.172     114.237           0
```

How can I segmented or split my DataFrame to tell python that run the function reading individuals ID sets? and then move to the next and so on

UPDATE: My function has these parameters:

```
N = df1.groupby('ID').size()          
max_time = N*(0.1)
frames = max_time/N
t_step=frames.item()



data = pd.DataFrame({'N':N,'max_time':max_time,'frames':frames})

print(data)

t=np.linspace(0.1, max_time.item(), N)
```

and the function calls some o the parameters and uses in the corresponding columns ['POSITION_X','POSITION_Y'] as follows:

```
def myfun(df1, frames, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y']):


        tau = t.copy()
        shifts = np.floor(tau / t_step).astype(np.int)
        msds_sum = np.zeros(shifts.size)
        delta_inv = np.arange(N+1)
        delta = delta_inv[N:0:-1]
        lag = np.arange(1,N+1)


        for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
            diffs = df1[coords] - df1[coords].shift(-shift)
            sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
            msds_sum[i] = sqdist.sum()
            msd = np.divide(msds_sum,delta)
            delta_inv = np.arange(N+1)

        msds = pd.DataFrame({'msd':msd, 'delta':delta, 'lag':lag})
        return msds

msd = myfun(df1, frames, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y'])
print(msd)
```

If I run the function on individual ID data sets, it works very well!! but how can I to indicate that repeat the function for each set of IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.groupby` and `apply()` to run a function on various groups as:

**Code:**

```
def apply_to_group(group):
    return (group['ID'] * 100) + group['POSITION_T']

df.groupby(['ID']).apply(apply_to_group)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    ID   POSITION_X  POSITION_Y  POSITION_T
    0     116.231     114.277           0
    0     116.131     114.376           1
    0     116.189     114.364           2
    1     116.150     114.398           0
    1     116.271     114.375           1
    2     116.157     114.296           0
    2     116.220     114.384           1
    2     116.221     114.280           2
    2     116.277     114.489           3
    3     116.172     114.237           0"""),
                 header=1)

def apply_to_group(group):
    return (group['ID'] * 100) + group['POSITION_T']

print(df)
print(df.groupby(['ID']).apply(apply_to_group))
```

**Results:**

```
   ID  POSITION_X  POSITION_Y  POSITION_T
0   0     116.231     114.277           0
1   0     116.131     114.376           1
2   0     116.189     114.364           2
3   1     116.150     114.398           0
4   1     116.271     114.375           1
5   2     116.157     114.296           0
6   2     116.220     114.384           1
7   2     116.221     114.280           2
8   2     116.277     114.489           3
9   3     116.172     114.237           0

ID   
0   0      0
    1      1
    2      2
1   3    100
    4    101
2   5    200
    6    201
    7    202
    8    203
3   9    300
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but "groupby" and "apply" don't work because previously I have to set some parameters that are dependent of my data set.

Comment: @JonathanPacheco, so what you just did was took a question that was answerable, that I actually had already spent time answering, and edited the question to one that is almost identical to a previous question of yours that is largely answerable.  Why did you do this?

Comment: @JonathanPacheco, So groupby and apply won't work? You should explain why.

Comment: The question keeps the same, I don't want that someone do my work, I just want some ideas and I tried to give more information. Apologize if I l gave you that impression